# Capitalization rule

Tags: capitalization

1. Instead of joining air force, he joined police department.
2. Instead of joining British air force, he joined British police department.

As per my knowledge air force and police are common nouns so we don't capitalize it, as in #1. But what about #2. Should they be capitalized there?

Comment: Get the grammar right before you write it. These are ungrammatical sentences. Suggest ELL.SU.

Comment: No, Hania, they should not.

Consider https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rules+for+capitalization+in+English&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=rules+for+capitalization+in+English&aqs=chrome..69i57.12438j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You should use the definite article for 'Air Force' and 'police', for example: 'Instead of joining *the* air force, he joined the police.  We also refer to the air force as the [Royal Air Force](https://www.raf.mod.uk/) here in Britain.

Comment: Hi Robbie! I have seen some English newspapers where they have capitalized 'Indian Air Force'.

Comment: Don't say "as per my knowledge"; it sounds funny. Say "as far as I know".

Comment: Indian Air Force is the name of an organisation, as is Royal Air Force.